# What is the reasoning behind "The final argument passed to useCallback changed size between renders ..." warning

Tags: reactjs

Opening this question here, because [StackOverflow is listed as a recommended place](https://reactjs.org/community/support.html#stack-overflow) for asking React-related questions in React docs.

I am looking for a reasoning behind throwing a `The final argument passed to useCallback changed size between renders. The order and size of this array must remain constant.` warning.

After looking into [React code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/d9e0485c84b45055ba86629dc20870faca9b5973/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L393-L416) it looks like React does not properly compare `prevDeps` and `nextDeps` arrays when they have different lengths.

The comparison function looks like this (some checks were omitted for brevity):

```js
function areHookInputsEqual(prevDeps,nextDeps) {
    for (let i = 0; i < prevDeps.length && i < nextDeps.length; i++) {
    if (Object.is(nextDeps[i], prevDeps[i])) {
      continue;
    }
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Which means:

- `areHookInputsEqual( ['a','b'], ['c','d'] ) === false` - correct
- `areHookInputsEqual( ['a','b','c'], ['a','b'] ) === true` - wrong
- `areHookInputsEqual( ['a','b'], ['a','b','c'] ) === true` - wrong
- `areHookInputsEqual( [], ['a'] ) === true` - wrong
- `areHookInputsEqual( ['a'], [] ) === true` - wrong

Why not to write this function as following and remove warning from the codebase?

```js
function areHookInputsEqual(prevDeps,nextDeps) {
  if (prevDeps.length !== nextDeps.length) {
    return false;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < prevDeps.length; i++) {
    if (Object.is(nextDeps[i], prevDeps[i])) {
      continue;
    }
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

### The use case which led to this question

We have a custom hook like this:

```js
function useLoadMessageKeys(messageKeys: string[]) {
  return React.useCallback(
    () => {
      return load(messageKeys)
    },
    messageKeys
  )
}
```

Because of current React implementation, `load` does not get called when `messageKeys` change from `[]` to `['a']`.

### Update (how we currently solved this)

```js
function areArraysEqual<T>(prevDeps: T[], nextDeps: T[]): boolean {
  if (prevDeps === nextDeps) {
    return true
  }
  if (prevDeps.length !== nextDeps.length) {
    return false
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < prevDeps.length; i++) {
    if (!Object.is(nextDeps[i], prevDeps[i])) {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
}

export function useLoadMessageKeys(messageKeys: string[]) {
  const messageKeysRef = React.useRef(messageKeys)
  if (!areArraysEqual(messageKeys, messageKeysRef.current)) {
    messageKeysRef.current = messageKeys
  }
  const currentMessageKeys = messageKeysRef.current
  return React.useCallback(
    () => load(currentMessageKeys),
    [currentMessageKeys]
  )
}
```

If the code linked in the question properly compared 2 arrays we'd avoid having this complexity.

Comment: Not sure what the question here is. Why do you think it should fail silently and *not* throw a warning?

Comment: In my honest opinion it can be written in a way it does not fail. I believe useCallback can understand that if the length of dependencies array changes it should execute the function.

Comment: Well you believe wrong – the array passed to the function should always be constant length, like the warning says. Variable-length array would make no sense so it's always a programmer error.

Comment: I don't see why you say "Variable-length array would make no sense". I added our use case to the question, as comments do not allow code blocks.

Comment: As it says in the comment in the React code you linked, "these arrays should be passed inline." It's been designed so that only inline arrays are allowed, so it correctly warns about passing a variable that can vary its length. You could post a ticket and try to discuss the design decision with the team but I wouldn't expect too much from that.

Comment: yeah. I am interesting in design decision for that. I don't feel like opening an issue in React repo which has more than 900 open issues will be the correct place for that.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reasoning is that the array of dependencies should always be exactly the list of variables used inside the effect. So in particular it can be statically determined and cannot change size. If it does change size, you're probably doing something more than just listing the dependencies, so it is warning you that you are not using the dependency list as intended.

You could use instead use a version of `messageKeys` that does not change if it is only shallow equal to the previous one (untested):

```js
const useMemoizedArray = (array: string[]) => {
  const [memoizedArray, setMemoizedArray] = React.useState(array);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Define `isShallowEqual` yourself somewhere
    if (!isShallowEqual(array, memoizedArray)) {
       setMemoizedArray(array);
    }
  }, [array, memoizedArray]);
  return memoizedArray;
};
```

```js
function useLoadMessageKeys(messageKeys: string[]) {
  const memoizedMessageKeys = useMemoizedArray(messageKeys);
  return React.useCallback(
    () => {
      return load(memoizedMessageKeys)
    },
    [memoizedMessageKeys]
  )
}
```

Comment: Being statically analyzable is a valid reason, but I don't know why it is so important. I am fine with a warning as it is a warning, but if it ends up with wrong behavior it sounds like a bug.

Please see "The use case which led to this question" section I added to question a couple of seconds ago.

Comment: In your use case, it could potentially be the case that the load function behaves differently if it is given an array that is not referentially equal but has exactly the same elements in the same order. In other words you are actually using the array itself, not the individual elements of the array, so depending on what the load function does it could behave incorrectly. How do you define `messageKeys`? An easy fix would be to use `[messageKeys]` as the dependency list, but then you would probably need to define `messageKeys` in a `useMemo` to avoid having it change at each render.

Comment: `messageKeys` reference always changes in my code, so using it directly will cause a lot of unnecessary rerenders. I am more interested in content of that array - it is the list of messages we load from the backend. If it changes we want to to load them.

Comment: See my edit for how to prevent useless calls to `load`.

Comment: I see the point. It will work. But it seems we’ll be writing a lot of code because React didn’t managed to handle that case for some reason.

Comment: How is `messageKeys` created? Can't you avoid recreating it if it didn't change?

Comment: I can, by adding logic similar to what you posted in consumer components, but I'd rather make my hook smarter, because otherwise such requirement will make my hook very hard to use.

Comment: I still don't understand why a new reference needs to be created at each render. Another solution would be to JSON.stringify it before using it as a dependency and then JSON.parse it inside the callback (or inside the load function). But I still feel like there is no reason for a new reference to be created in the first place if the value doesn't change.

Comment: sorry for formatting here. We have a hook which you call like 

`useLocalizations({ 
  msgGreeting: {
    key: 'msg.hello',
    fallback: 'Hello {name}', 
    args: {name: 'Bob' }
  },
  msgBye: {
    key: 'msg.bye',
    fallback: 'Bye {name}', 
    args: {name: 'Kevin' }
  }
})
`

The `messageKeys` array is computed from that object. In this case it will be `['msg.hello', 'msg.bye']`.

It will be inconvenient to keep that object unchanged as `args` may change between re-renders.

Comment: I updated question with our current solution, inspired by your answer (upvoted it). Thanks! However I am still interesting is knowing why React didn't fixed that in their own code. The code I linked was not modified in 4 years, which makes me think there was some design decision I am not aware of.